# Activate a maven profile if executable exists in PATH

Tags: maven

Is it possible to activate a maven profile based on a presence of an executable in the PATH?

Comment: What is the intention of this? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to run a npm script (typescript compile) if npm/node is available, not everyone has npm because for the backend guys it's not needed.